# Reading the SECURITY_ENABLED flag of Group in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, integer-overflow, active-directory-group

I'm trying to read the [SECURITY_ENABLED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223142.aspx) flag of a groups groupType property. The problem is that the value I retreive by using

```
DirectoryEntry entry...
entry.Properties["groupType"].Value;
```

is an `int32`, whose range is [-2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,648 (or -0x7FFFFFFF to 0x80000000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx)

[image: quickWatch]

So anytime there is the `GROUP_TYPE_SECURITY_ENABLED` and any other arbitraty flag set, the numeric value exceeds the the range of an int32 and an overflow happens.

[image: groupTypeScreen]

Does anyone know how to avoid this overflow in order to read the correct value?

Comment: does the flag have to be an int 0x80000000 fits into a unit nicely.

Comment: By default, Int32 is signed. Can you use UInt32??

Comment: Entry.Properties["groupType"].Value returns -2147483646. When I try to cast it to an uint I get an InvalidCastException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `UInt32` as the type of your enumeration `GroupType` as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum GroupType : uint
{
    BUILTIN_LOCAL_GROUP = 0x00000001,
    ACCOUNT_GROUP       = 0x00000002,
    RESOURCE_GROUP      = 0x00000004,
    UNIVERSAL_GROUP     = 0x00000008,
    APP_BASIC_GROUP     = 0x00000010,
    APP_QUERY_GROUP     = 0x00000020,
    SECURITY_ENABLED    = 0x80000000
}
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.

**EDIT:** OK, I wasn't sure if `Entry` was an object you created, or part of the Active Directory API. Having said that, I quick created the following variables in a project I'm currently working on and compiled as follows:

```
// I only made it static so I could get my compiler to compile this in something I'm currently
// working on. It's not necessary for it to be static.
static int SECURITY_ENABLED = 0x80000000;

int newValue = SECURITY_ENABLED | 1;
```

I did not get any compile-time errors. In fact, re-looking at the value `0x80000000`, it's well with in the range of an `Int32`.

Re-looking at your code above, on what line exactly, are you getting the error? I see this suspicios code:

```
if (groupTypes.Count == 1)
{
    var  firstFlag = (int) groupTypes[0];

    // What is this checking, exactly?
    // Is this where the error is occurring?
    var longFlag = -(((long) flag) - firstFlag);

    if ((longFlag == 0x80000000)) // Extra parentheses here...just a formatting thing
        groupTypes.Add(GroupType.SECURITY_ENABLED);
}
```

Perhaps this code could be simplified?

```
public List<GroupType> GetGroupType()
{
    var groupTypes = new List<GroupType>();
    var flag = (GroupType) this.Entry.Properties["groupType"].Value;

    if (flag & GroupType.ACCOUNT_GROUP > 0)
        groupTypes.Add(GroupType.ACCOUNT_GROUP;
    else if (flag & GroupType.APP_BASIC_GROUP > 0)
        groupTypes.Add(GroupType.APP_BASIC_GROUP);

    // ... Other else if ad nauseum ...

    else if (flag & GroupType.SERUCITY_ENABLED > 0)
        groupTypes.Add(GroupType.SECURITY_ENABLED);

    return groupTypes;
}
```

If you really need an `ArrayList()` for whatever reason, you could then just do `return groupTypes.ToArray<int>();`

HTH.

Comment: as already said: Entry.Properties["groupType"].Value returns -2147483646. When I try to cast it to an uint I get an InvalidCastException. So I can't even combine the returnvalue with the enums

Comment: in debug mode you can see, that it is a signed integer
http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2369/grouptype.png

Comment: the "suspicious" code is a workaround, to read the flag, even there is a bufferoverflow. For now it works, if there are two flags set. First I get the flag, that is not the SERUCITY_ENABLED flag. Then I convert the given flagvalue and convert it to a long in order to restore the initial value, by subtracting the first flag's value, so I can check if the SERUCITY_ENABLED flag is set. Specifically I get an COMException, when I try to set the flag like this: 

var val = (long) ((int) this.Entry.Properties["groupType"].Value);     this.Entry.Properties["groupType"].Value = val & ~0x80000000;

Comment: this screenshot shows, that I get a compiler error, when I try to assign 0x80000000 to an int
http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/6046/errorowc.png

Comment: that's interesting that you get that little pop-up. I got no such compile error (and I did compile) nor did I even get a warning from Visual Studio before I compiled. The popup does not look like a standard Visual Studio-type error. Could it be the tooling you're using that's fooling you into thinking that you can't assign this value? I assure you, I can, I just executed the code in question.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you just mentioned COM. I seem to remember something about COM not liking `long` values. Before setting an integer-type value on a COM object, make sure if the .NET value is a `long` that you cast it back to an `int`.

Comment: You were right after all! I had to come back to this issue and now I was able to cast to Uint32 without any problem. Idk what I did wrong back then, that it wouldn't cast from Int32 to Uint32.

Comment: @Paweł I'm glad you were able to figure it out and that I could help.

Answer (score 5):

Referencing @fourpastmidnight's answer and these articles [object-group-attribute-grouptype](http://adsearch-winzero.blogspot.com/2006/04/object-group-attribute-grouptype.html) and [msdn Group-Type attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675935(v=vs.85).aspx), I was able to find a solution that does not require casting to `uint` or parsing through an `if ... else if` statement.

Seeing the negative values from the first link and from @wodzu's comment on the return value of -2147483646, I tried inverting the SECURITY_ENALBED value to -0x80000000.

```
[System.Flags]
public enum GroupType
{
    BUILTIN_LOCAL_GROUP = 0x00000001,
    ACCOUNT_GROUP       = 0x00000002,
    RESOURCE_GROUP      = 0x00000004,
    UNIVERSAL_GROUP     = 0x00000008,
    APP_BASIC_GROUP     = 0x00000010,
    APP_QUERY_GROUP     = 0x00000020,
    SECURITY_ENABLED    = -0x80000000
}
```

Now when getting the value and casting as GroupType

```
var groupType = (GroupType)this.Entry.Properties["groupType"].Value
```

You can then use .ToString() on the GroupType value which will return a comma separated string of each flag.

Or you can use the .HasFlag method to check if it is a Security Group

```
bool IsSecurityGroup = groupType.HasFlag(GroupType.SECURITY_ENABLED);
```

Answer (score 0):

**A little Python to decode groupType AD attribute value**

1. prepare a dictionary with all the defined combination. (ref. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-grouptype)

   ```
    gt_decode_dict = {
        "0x00000001": "SYSTEM CREATED",     # Specifies a group that is created by the system.
        "0x00000002": "GLOBAL",             # Specifies a group with global scope.
        "0x00000004": "LOCAL",              # Specifies a group with domain local scope.
        "0x00000008": "UNIVERSAL",          # Specifies a group with universal scope.
        "0x00000010": "APP_BASIC",          # Specifies an APP_BASIC group for Windows Server Authorization Manager.
        "0x00000020": "APP_QUERY",          # Specifies an APP_QUERY group for Windows Server Authorization Manager.
        "0x80000000": "SECURITY"}           # Specifies a security group. If this flag is not set, then the group is a distribution group.
   ```
2. define a function to decode the groupType value

   ```
    def decode_gt(_group_type):
    #
    # Decode groupType attribute.
    # 
    global gt_decode_dict
    _delta = 0

    _translatedGT = ""
    if _group_type > 0:
        _hex_gt = hex(_group_type)
        _gt_work = int(_hex_gt[2:])
        _gt_work = str(_gt_work).rjust(8, "0")
        _gt_key = r'0x' + str(_gt_work)
        _translatedGT += "DISTRIBUTION - "
    else:
        _delta = 2147483648 - abs(_group_type)
        if (_delta % 2) > 0:
            _translatedGT = "SECURITY - SYSTEM CREATED - "
            _gt_key = r'0x' + str(_delta - 1).rjust(8, "0")
        else:
            _translatedGT = "SECURITY - "
            _gt_key = r'0x' + str(_delta).rjust(8, "0")

    if _gt_key in gt_decode_dict.keys():
        _translatedGT += gt_decode_dict[_gt_key]
    else:
        notification("   Invalid groupType key: " + str(_gt_key) + ". Values dec: " + str(_group_type) + " delta:" + str(_delta) + ", for group " + _group_dn, 4)
        _translatedGT += " Error "

    return _translatedGT
   ```
3. call the function passing the groupType as an Integer

   groupType = decode_gt(int(_groupType))